# Getting Error in retrieving data from Google Spreadsheet API using Structure Query (sq) in Android

Tags: android, url, google-sheets, url-encoding, google-sheets-api

I am working with Google Spreadsheet API in Android. I am successfully done with the integration and able to retrieve the rows. But facing a little problem in search functionality. I am having 3-4 different search for the spreadsheet. The problem is that in my spreadsheet in some columns I am having space between words.

For e.g Hello World is a value in row number 5 and the header name for this row is let say test.

So when i search for the **Hello World** it is throwing **InValidEntryException : Bad Request.**

**I also try with URLEncoder.encode(String url) and also replace the space with %20.** But none of that work for me. I know i am getting the error because of the space but don't know how to resolve. Tried with this 2 things but still struggling with the error.

If anyone has any idea please kindly help. Below is the error log.

Error Log :-

```
10-09 14:26:29.048: I/System.out(1009): URL ==> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/tl5vghRJs8_wuVQWnk5TnhA/od6/private/full?sq=streetname=bal%20bay
10-09 14:26:30.327: D/dalvikvm(1009): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 46% free 3492K/6407K, external 920K/1417K, paused 18ms+14ms
10-09 14:26:31.847: I/System.out(1009): Service
10-09 14:26:31.877: W/System.err(1009): com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
10-09 14:26:31.887: W/System.err(1009): Parse error: null
10-09 14:26:31.967: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
10-09 14:26:32.217: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
10-09 14:26:32.228: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
10-09 14:26:32.228: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
10-09 14:26:32.228: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
10-09 14:26:32.228: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
10-09 14:26:32.228: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
10-09 14:26:32.237: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
10-09 14:26:32.259: W/System.err(1009):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
10-09 14:26:32.259: W/System.err(1009):     at com.test.voter.SearchActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(SearchActivity.java:144)
10-09 14:26:32.259: W/System.err(1009):     at com.test.voter.SearchActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(SearchActivity.java:1)
10-09 14:26:32.259: W/System.err(1009):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-09 14:26:32.278: W/System.err(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-09 14:26:32.287: W/System.err(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-09 14:26:32.287: W/System.err(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-09 14:26:32.312: W/System.err(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-09 14:26:32.312: W/System.err(1009):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

**EDIT**

```
1)URL listFeedUrl = new  URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString() + "?sq=" + URLEncoder.encode("streetname=\"164Th\"")).toURL(); 

2)URL listFeedUrl = new  URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString() + "?sq=" + URLEncoder.encode("streetnumber=\"1923\"%20and%20streetname=\"164Th\"")).toURL();
```

(1) Works perfectly fine but when used multiple parameter (2) it does not work, giving the same InvalidEntryException again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could search the issues list for [issue 2308](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2308&can=1&q=label%3AAPI-Spreadsheets%20query&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Opened%20Summary) and notice comment 3:

> if you just wrap the name in quotes, it works fine.  You can even use spaces in your column names here.
>
> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/${KEY}/records/0?sq="5B"+%3D+3
>   https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/${KEY}/records/0?sq="the+cat"+%3D+3

... and hope that what was not documented in respect of the records feed was actually implemented in respect of the list feed, despite the transition to a 'WontFix' status later.

Comment: Hello David, Thank you so much for such a useful information. It solved my one problem but it raises another problem for me. I am having multiple criteria like name=\"Hello World\"%20and%20id=\"1\". Now I am again getting the error of Bad Request. So my question is that does this causes error because of and condition? Because when i search individually it works perfectly fine but in multiple values it throws error.

Comment: Don't know. I suspect a poorly-tested parser.  Try using '+' in lieu of %20.  Try using '&&' in lieu of 'and'.  Make sure you're encoding everything correctly.  Make sure you read the text of the 400 response for clues.  For shorter dev cycles when hacking, fiddle the query using OAuth Playground.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your kind response. Actually I am not doing OAuth in my app, I am just using the setCredentials method of the SpreadsheetService so is that a problem? Because other than this rest of the things works completely perfect so i didn't use the OAuth flow and directly set the user credentials.

Comment: I also tried in OAuth 2.0 Playground but I am getting the same error of parse error : null. I think that and condition will not work with the solution that you mentioned.

Comment: Hey I achieved my functionality. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the now-defunct [GData 2.0 Protocol Guide](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries) (also on the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100209122348/http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#Queries)) says in respect of the "q" parameter:

> list search terms separated by spaces, in the form q=term1 term2 term3. (As with all of the query parameter values, the spaces must be URL encoded)

However, the defunct-so-much-as-to-be-unpublished-anymore-by-Google [Spreadsheets Data API 3.0 Reference Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20100211022141/http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/reference.html) is a bit light-on with information about parameters to the list-feed-specific "sq" parameter.

I'd probably try wrapping the search term in quotes "like so" (and URLencoding them).  That's the technique which the "q" parameter uses for delimiting entire phrases.

If that didn't work, I'd file an [issue report](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3AAPI-Spreadsheets+search&colspec=API+ID+Type+Status+Priority+Stars+Opened+Summary&cells=tiles) complaining about inadequate documentation.  Feel free to cite [my prior complaint](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-spreadsheets-api/A4gK3JZZXLo/8w6zdeU78VUJ).

Comment: Not that reporting an issue will mean much.  Of the 193 issues ever reported against the spreadsheets API, only 19 ever made it to the 'fixed' status.

Comment: it's interesting that they don't document the `sq` parameter for list-based feeds, but it seems like the 2.0 `q` parameter still works.  Thanks for pointing out the older API docs.  I would have never thought to look there.